# If the sum of cubes of $a,b,c,d$ is $1$, then $\frac{1}{1-bcd}+\frac{1}{1-cda}+\frac{1}{1-dab}+\frac{1}{1-abc}\le \frac{16}{3}$

Tags: multivariable-calculus, inequality, substitution, symmetric-polynomials, uvw

> $a,b,c,d>0$ satisfying $a^3+b^3+c^3+d^3=1$. Prove
>   $$\frac{1}{1-bcd}+\frac{1}{1-cda}+\frac{1}{1-dab}+\frac{1}{1-abc}\le \frac{16}{3}$$

I tried to go the normal way, by Cauchy-Schwarz, but that doesn't work. So I tried to incorporate this newly learned idea, since $a,b,c,d<1$ we can write the left as a power series:
$$\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}(bcd)^n+(cda)^n+(dab)^n+(abc)^n$$
If we can show, $(bcd)^n+(cda)^n+(dab)^n+(abc)^n\ge (K(a^3+b^3+c^3+d^3))^n$ for some suitable constant $K$ we can finish. But I can't really do it. Can someone help me?

Comment: For $n=1$, your last inequality doesn't look so promising. I guess same can be stated for $n>1$, but that needs verification.

Comment: Yes, I see it now. But do you have any other proof of it? @QuangHoang

Comment: Actually your reasoning is pretty good. I'm under the impression that all inequalities should be flipped. For example, if $a,b,c$ are close to zero, then the LHS is close to $1$.

Comment: I would try a different approach. For a,b,c,d satisfying a³+b³+c³+d³, find some maximum value of the product abcd ( should be less than 1). Some calculus would be of use here. From there, you should be able to derive the inequality if your maximum is strong enough.

Comment: @Assaultous2 the point in comments above is that the inequality is incorrect. For eg if three variables tend to zero, the LHS is arbitrarily close to 4, clearly less than RHS.

Comment: True!  I see. Yes, the inequality is incorrect.

Comment: However, I intuitively feel there should be a minimum for the LHS. It may be smaller than 16/3 but I feel there should be one.

Comment: @QuangHoang Check $(a, b, c, d) \to (0, 0, 0, 1) \implies LHS \to 4$.

Comment: Checked, then minimal/infimum is $4$, as each summand is $\ge 1$. And now that I realized my other comment was wrong, I can't edit it.

Comment: @Assaultous2 If we allow the variables to possibly be zero, then we are looking at a continuous function on a compact domain.  This is enough to conclude that it attains a maximum and a minimum.

Comment: Yes, the inequality should be reversed. (This problem appears in the current issue of Mathematical Reflections, published by Titu Andreescu.)

Comment: 0

down vote
 

Yes, the inequality should be reversed. (This problem appears in the current issue of Mathematical Reflections, published by Titu Andreescu.)

Comment: But how to do it then? Can someone help me? Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 1):

The AM-GM inequality yields

$$ abcd \le \frac{1}{4 \sqrt[3]{4}} \iff abc \le \frac{1}{4 \sqrt[3]{4}d} \iff \frac{1}{1-abc} \le \frac{1}{1 - \frac{1}{4 \sqrt[3]{4} d}}. $$
It follows that 
$$ \sum_{cyclic} \frac{1}{1-abc} \le \sum_{cyclic} \frac{4 \sqrt[3]{4} d}{4 \sqrt[3]{4} d -1}.$$
Therefore it is sufficient to show that
$$ \sum_{cyclic} \frac{4 \sqrt[3]{4} d}{4 \sqrt[3]{4} d -1} \le \frac{16}{3} \iff 4 - \sum_{cyclic} \frac{-1}{4 \sqrt[3]{4} d - 1} \le \frac{16}{3} \iff \sum_{cyclic} \frac{-1}{4 \sqrt[3]{4} d - 1} \ge \frac{-4}{3} \iff \sum_{cyclic} \frac{1}{1 - 4 \sqrt[3]{4}d} \ge \frac{-4}{3}. $$

Now using a form of the Cauchy-Schwarz inequality usually referred to as Titu's Lemma (after Titu Andreescu), we find that

$$ 
\sum_{cyclic} \frac{1}{1 - 4 \sqrt[3]{4}d} \ge \frac{(1 + 1 +1 + 1)^2}{\sum_{cyclic} (1 - 4 \sqrt[3]{4}d)} = \frac{16}{4 - 4 \sqrt[3]{4}} (a + b + c + d).
 $$

Hence it suffices to show that

$$ \frac{16}{4 - 4 \sqrt[3]{4}(a + b + c + d)} \ge \frac{-4}{3} \iff  \frac{1}{1 -  \sqrt[3]{4}(a + b + c + d)} \ge \frac{-1}{3} \iff 3 \ge -1 + \sqrt[3]{4} (a + b + c + d) \iff 4 \ge \sqrt[3]{4} (a + b + c + d) \iff \sqrt[3]{16} \ge a + b + c + d. $$
The last inequality follows from Hölder's inequality since
$$ (a^3 + b^3 + c^3 + d^3)(1 + 1 + 1 + 1)(1 + 1 + 1 + 1) \ge (a + b + c + d)^3 \iff \sqrt[3]{16} \ge a + b + c + d. $$
Therefore the conclusion follows and equality holds for $ a = b = c = d = \frac{1}{\sqrt[3]{4}}.$

Comment: This methods is not true..

Comment: I made two crucial LaTeX errors, which I have corrected. The proof is correct as it appears now.

Comment: I mean that: may$1-\sqrt[3]{4}(a+b+c+d)<0$,so $$\dfrac{1}{1-\sqrt[3]{4}(a+b+c+d)}\ge\dfrac{-1}{3}\Longleftrightarrow 3\ge -1+\sqrt[3]{4}(a+b+c+d)$$ is wrong!

Comment: Thank you, *math110*.  You are right. Several of the terms may be either positive or negative, thereby negating my use of basic properties of inequalities, including the Cauchy-Schwarz inequality. I'll keep trying to fix my proof.

Comment: OK. I checked with a very experienced problem proposer/solver, and it turns out that *his* solution is also flawed. He found that LHS $\le M$, but unfortunately $M \ge 16/3.$  This inequality is more subtle than we think. *Maple* calculations suggest that the proposed inequality *is* true however.

Answer (score 1):

Let $a+b+c+d=4u$, $ab+ac+bc+ad+bd+cd=6v^2$, $abc+abd+acd+bcd=4w^3$ 
and $abcd=t^4$.

Also let  $abc=x$, $abd=y$, $acd=z$ and $bcd=p$.

Hence, we need to prove that:
$$\sum_{cyc}\frac{1}{1-x}\leq\frac{16}{3}$$ or
$$4-7\sum_{cyc}x+10(xy+xz+yz+xp+yp+zp)-13\sum_{cyc}xyz+16xyzp\geq0$$ or
$$4(64u^3-72uv^2+12w^3)^4-28w^3(64u^3-72uv^2+12w^3)^3+$$
$$+60v^2t^4(64u^3-72uv^2+12w^3)^2-52ut^8(64u^3-72uv^2+12w^3)+16t^{12}\geq0$$ or
$$64(16u^3-18uv^2+3w^3)^4-112w^3(16u^3-18uv^2+3w^3)^3+$$
$$+60v^2t^4(16u^3-18uv^2+3w^3)^2-13ut^8(16u^3-18uv^2+3w^3)+t^{12}\geq0.$$
We'll show that $$60v^2(16u^3-18uv^2+3w^3)^2-13ut^4(16u^3-18uv^2+3w^3)+t^{8}\geq$$
$$\geq48v^2(16u^3-18uv^2+3w^3)^2.$$
Indeed, we need to show that
$$t^4\leq\frac{1}{2}(16u^3-18uv^2+3w^3)\left(13u-\sqrt{169u^2-48v^2}\right)$$
and since $t^4\leq v^4$, it's enough to prove that
$$v^4\leq\frac{1}{2}(16u^3-18uv^2+3w^3)\left(13u-\sqrt{169u^2-48v^2}\right).$$
By Schur $w^3\geq4uv^2-3u^3$.

Thus, it remains to prove that
$$v^4\leq\frac{1}{2}(7u^3-6uv^2)\left(13u-\sqrt{169u^2-48v^2}\right),$$
which is obvious because $u^2\geq v^2$.

Id est, it remains to prove that:
$$64(16u^3-18uv^2+3w^3)^4-112w^3(16u^3-18uv^2+3w^3)^3+$$
$$+48v^2t^4(16u^3-18uv^2+3w^3)^2\geq0$$ or
$$4(16u^3-18uv^2+3w^3)^2-7w^3(16u^3-18uv^2+3w^3)+3v^2t^4\geq0.$$
Now, $(a-b)^2(c-d)^2+(a-c)^2(b-d)^2+(a-d)^2(b-c)^2\geq0$ gives $t^4\geq4uw^3-3v^4$.

Hence, it remains to prove that $f(w^3)\geq0$, where
$$f(w^3)=4(16u^3-18uv^2+3w^3)^2-7w^3(16u^3-18uv^2+3w^3)+3v^2(4uw^3-3v^4).$$
Now, by Schur
$$f'(w^3)=30w^3+272u^3-294uv^2>$$
$$>22(4uv^2-3w^3)+272u^3-294uv^2=206u(u^2-v^2)\geq0,$$
which says that it's remains to prove $f(w^3)\geq0$ for a minimal value of $w^3$.
Now, $a$, $b$, $c$ and $d$ are positive roots of the following equation
$$(x-a)(x-b)(x-c)(x-d)=0$$ or
$$x^4-4ux^3+6v^2x^2-4w^3x+t^4=0,$$
which says that the equation 
$$(x^4-4ux^3+6v^2x^2-4w^3x+t^4)'=0$$ or
$$x^3-3ux^2+3v^2x-w^3=0$$ 
has three positive roots.
Let $k$, $l$ and $m$ are the roots, which says that

$3u=k+l+m$, $3v^2=kl+km+lm$ and $w^3=klm$

and the equation $w^3=x^3-3ux^2+3v^2x$ has three positive roots.

Now, let $u$ and $v^2$ are constants. We see that $w^3$ gets a minimal value,

when the line $y=w^3$ is a tangent line to the graph of $y=x^3-3ux^2+3v^2x$,

which happens for equality case of two variables or else we must check $w^3\rightarrow0^+$.

Id est, it's enough to prove that $f(w^3)\geq0$ in the following cases.

1. $w^3\rightarrow0^+$.

Let $m\rightarrow0^+$ and $l=1$. We can assume that $l=1$ because $f(w^3)\geq0$ is homogeneous.

Thus, we need to prove here
$$4(16u^3-18uv^2)^2-9v^6\geq0$$ or
$$4\left(\frac{16(k+1)^3}{27}-2(k+1)k\right)^2-\frac{k^3}{3}\geq0$$ or
$$1024k^6-768k^5-624k^4+2093k^3-624k^2-768k+1024\geq0,$$
which is obvious.

2. $l=m=1$.

In this case we obtain
$$4\left(\frac{16(k+2)^3}{27}-2(k+2)(2k+1)+3k\right)^2-$$
$$-7k\left(\frac{16(k+2)^3}{27}-2(k+2)(2k+1)+3k\right)+(2k+1)\left(\frac{4(k+2)k}{3}-\frac{(2k+1)^2}{3}\right)\geq0$$ or
$$(k-1)^2(1024k^4+512k^3-2064k^2-100k+1357)\geq0,$$
which is obviously true.

Done!